# How to serialize enclosing tag with no nodes in Java SimpleXML

Tags: java, xml, simple-framework, canonicalization

How can I serialize XML using Java Simple Framework XML to include full closing tags when node is empty.

I currently get:

```xml
<data:img/>
```

but I need result for Canonicalization such as:

```xml
<data:img></data:img>
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a solution. Similar to: [Prevent inclusion of empty tag for an empty ElementList in an ElementListUnion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14443749/prevent-inclusion-of-empty-tag-for-an-empty-elementlist-in-an-elementlistunion)

I added new element to the Java object with which causes the SimpleXML to include empty tag content:

```java
    @Text
    protected String dummytext = "";
```